# How to find the horizontal and vertical asymptote

Tags: calculus, limits

So I'm having trouble figuring out the horizontal asymptote for function given by

$$
f(x) = \arctan(x) + \frac{3x}{x-2}.
$$

I've figured out that the vertical asymptote is $x= 2$, but I can't find the horizontal asymptote.

Comment: Deal with each individually - what does $\arctan(x)$ approach for large $x$? If $x$ is large, $x-2$ is very close to $x$ - so then what is $3x/x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain of $f(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}-\{2\}$

The point excluded in the domain $x=2$ is a vertical asymptote because
$$\underset{x\to 2^-}{\text{lim}}f(x)=-\infty;\;\underset{x\to 2^+}{\text{lim}}f(x)=+\infty$$
The limits at infinity
$$\underset{x\to +\infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{3 x}{x-2}+\arctan x\right)=3+\frac{\pi }{2}$$

$$\underset{x\to -\infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{3 x}{x-2}+\arctan x\right)=3-\frac{\pi }{2}$$

therefore there are two distinct horizontal asymptotes $y=3+\frac{\pi }{2}$ at $+\infty$ and  $y=3-\frac{\pi }{2}$ at $-\infty$

See the picture below
$$...$$

---

$$...$$
[image]